# I Can't close the socket connection between the server and the client

Tags: c, string, sockets

I'm having a issue when i try to close the connection from the client, i want to close the connection with the server when the client write a string like "q" and i do a strcmp just after the message from client is read by the server, but is not working because is not passing the comparison.

Here is the code for the server

```
    while(1){

    if((n = read(newsocketfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer))) > 0)
            printf("(Mlength %d) message from Client:  %s\n",n,buffer);
    else{

        close(socketfd);
        close(newsocketfd);
        error("Error reading message \n");
    }

    if(strcmp("q",&buffer[n]) == 0)
        printf("El cliente intenta cerrar la conexión %s\n",&buffer[n]);
    else
        printf("Se recibieron datos desde el cliente %s\n",&buffer[n]);

    if(write(newsocketfd,response,255) > 0)
            printf("Writing response to Client socket \n");
    else
            error("Error writing message \n");
    }

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

Here is the code for the client

```
   do{
printf("Please, type your message: ");
bzero(buffer,256);
fgets(buffer,255,stdin);

n = write(socketfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
if(n < 0 )
    error("Error writing to socket \n");
else
    printf("...Message sent \n");

n = read(socketfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
if(n < 0 )
        error("Error writing to socket \n");
    else
        printf("\n Message from server: %s \n",buffer);

}while(strcmp("q",buffer)!=0);
```

Comment: Well, assuming that the buffer is a null-terminated string that can be safely printed with printf("%s..) is inviting disaster, and then you try to compare "q" with the undefined characters just after the section of the buffer that has been read: '&buffer[n]'.  Check ALL your server and client code for invalid assumptions - that received data is guaranteed null-terminated and that TCP transfers messages longer than one byte - it does not, it only transfers octet/byte streams, and generally requires multiple read calls to transfer an application-level protocol unit.

Comment: Network Programming has a couple traps that you have to know about before starting. I suggest reading one of the books on network programming before progressing further. Otherwise you will constantly run into things that seem unintuitive.

Answer (score 2):

```
read(newsocketfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)))
```

Buffer overflow -----------------------^

```
if ((n = read(newsocketfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1)) > 0) { /* Note -1 */
    buffer[n] = '\0'; /* read() doesn't add a trailing 0 */
    printf("(Mlength %d) message from Client:  %s\n",n,buffer);
} else {
    ...
```

---

```
if (strcmp("q", &buffer[n]) == 0) /* you are reading NUL ('\0') */
```

change to:

```
if (strcmp("q", buffer) == 0)
```

Comment: It seems that the buffer will never have only the char q , it always have n+1 characters and is because of that the validation doesn't work, could you please give me and advice for close the connection between the two programs?

Comment: Have you tried using `sizeof(buffer) - 1` or `strlen(buffer)`? (same for `write()`)

Comment: checking the strlen works good and the connection is closed, but i want to specify a string like ("quit") for close the connection

Comment: Take a look to http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1044780608&answer=1108255660